# Spring Security Resource Server gives a 401 when adding a custom SecurityFilterChain

Tags: spring-security

I am running a sample resource server using Spring Boot and when I run it without adding a custom SecurityFilterChain bean, everything works fine. When I provide a custom SecurityFilterChain it gives a 401 and sometimes a 403.

Here is my Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
}

group = "com.resource.server"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {  
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Here is what I have in my application.properties:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=https://mydomain.auth0.com/
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-audience=aud-name
```

Here is my SecurityFilterChain class

```
package com.resource.server.resourceserver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

Here is the basic controller I use to test the application:

```
package com.resource.server.resourceserver;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHi(){
        return "Hi";
    }
}
```

Here is what I get in the logs:

```
2023-12-21T08:13:55.404+02:00  INFO 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-21T08:13:55.405+02:00  INFO 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-12-21T08:13:55.408+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /
2023-12-21T08:13:55.409+02:00  WARN 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.w.s.h.HandlerMappingIntrospector     : Cache miss for REQUEST dispatch to '/' (previous null). Performing CorsConfiguration lookup. This is logged once only at WARN level, and every time at TRACE.
2023-12-21T08:13:55.414+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-12-21T08:13:55.420+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8082/?continue to session
2023-12-21T08:13:55.420+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-12-21T08:13:55.420+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@6dd20239
2023-12-21T08:13:55.422+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-12-21T08:13:55.422+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-12-21T08:13:55.422+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8082/error?continue to session
2023-12-21T08:13:55.422+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2023-12-21T08:13:55.423+02:00 DEBUG 181669 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@6dd20239
```

I've tried a few tutorials and tried starting from scratch. I've also tried Googling the log error messages but I did not find anything that really made much sense.

I made this update and it helped fix it - code from here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html.
I don't quite understand what was the issue with the initial version though. If anyone could help me understand, it would be great

````
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DirectlyConfiguredJwkSetUri {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt(jwt -> jwt
                    .jwkSetUri("https://idp.example.com/.well-known/jwks.json")
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}```
````

Comment: If you change `.anyRequest().authenticated()` to `.anyRequest().permitAll()` it will work and you can access the resource, because I am sure you don’t pass authentication.

Comment: I have a token that needs to be validated. permitAll() does work but then it does not check the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main different of first way and second one of your configuration is in

`.httpBasic(withDefaults());` that mean you enabled HTTP `Basic` authentication for an application, that is wrong in your case because you have to configure [Resource Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/index.html) based on your `gradle` dependencies imports:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server")
```

And the second configuration fix it because you declared how to threat it.

```
oauth2ResourceServer()
```

And also how you pointed you have a `JWT` token that is default one in this kind of configuration. More deep details about it [Resource Server JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html)

Also

```
.jwt(jwt -> jwt
                    .jwkSetUri("https://idp.example.com/.well-known/jwks.json")
                )
```

> If the authorization server doesn’t support any configuration
> endpoints, or if Resource Server must be able to start up
> independently from the authorization server